# Equation involving Bessel functions.

Tags: roots, bessel-functions

I have a mechanical engineering background. Can someone help me to find out zeroes of Bessel function?

the equation:

$$\Gamma(f,\beta)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_1(f\alpha_k)\tanh(a_k\beta)/[\alpha_k^2J_0^2(\alpha_k)]$$

I know the value of $f$ and $\beta$. How can I find $\alpha$? They are the zeros of Bessel function $J_1(x)$.

Comment: There are some references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Zeros_of_the_Bessel_function) to numerical methods.

Comment: You might want to clarify whether you need the exact solution or just an approximation.

Comment: @cpiegore Approximation. as there are infinite terms

Comment: There is a [Bessel J Zero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselJZero%5B1%2Cn%5D) function

Comment: Instead of just asking about the $\alpha_k$ which can all be computed to as much precision as you want with e.g. @TymaGaidash comment, the more relevant question is how to approximate this. Namely the questions of if you cutoff the sum at some large $k$, are you getting closer to an answer and if so can you bound how far off as a function of the cutoff $K$. And if that way of calculating approximations doesn't work (or work well) what sort of resummation (manipulations that can make sum converge better) do you need to do.